# WowSlider - how to get rid of extra space at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I've been playing with `margin-bottom` for an hour and I can't get the gray bar to disappear at the bottom of my screen.

Here's the pertinent code...

```
        <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section --> <!-- add to the <body> of your page -->
        <div id="wowslider-container1">
            <div class="ws_images">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/b25b1439x1080.jpg" alt="jquery slideshow" title="B25b-1439x1080" id="wows1_0"/></a></li>
                    <li><img src="data1/images/mb1439x1080.jpg" alt="Ma1-25b-1439x1080" title="M1-25b-1439x1080" id="wows1_1"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ws_thumbs">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" title="B25b-1439x1080"><img src="data1/tooltips/b25b1439x1080.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    <a href="#" title="M-25b-1439x1080"><img src="data1/tooltips/m125b1439x1080.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--<div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.com">wowslider.com</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.5m</div>-->
        <!--<div class="ws_shadow"></div>-->
        </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/idle-timer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
        <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what to do?

Playing with `height` isn't working either.
I colored the `body` red, so you can see it sticking out from under the `wowslider-container1`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than using height. set the position as fixed and then the top,right,bottom and left to 0

```
#wowslider-container1{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: well what do you know? That worked (on the right element). Thanks!